# How to select date based on conditions in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like below:

```
    Date1     Date2     
 25-11-2020  23-11-2020       
             27-11-2020      
 26-11-2020                   
 29-11-2020  27-11-2020        
             29-11-2020       
 23-11-2020  27-11-2020
```

I need to apply the below conditions on the dataframe:

1. If Date1 and Date2 are present then Select Date 1
2. Date 1 is null or not present select Date 2

**Expected Output**

```
Date1     Date2     Date_Select 
 25-11-2020  23-11-2020  25-11-2020      
             27-11-2020  27-11-2020      
 26-11-2020              26-11-2020      
 29-11-2020  27-11-2020  29-11-2020      
             29-11-2020  29-11-2020      
 23-11-2020  27-11-2020  23-11-2020
```

How can this be in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fillna:

```
df['Date1'].fillna(df['Date2'])
```

Or

```
df['Date1'].combine_first(df['Date2'])
```

Output:

```
0    25-11-2020
1    27-11-2020
2    26-11-2020
3    29-11-2020
4    29-11-2020
5    23-11-2020
Name: Date1, dtype: object
```